# Parse push notification install error

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, notifications, push

Hi I installed Parse push notification. When I try to open my app, my app was shutting down.

Logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.goksuahmet.mekim/com.goksuahmet.mekim.splash}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParsePlugins is already initialized
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3930)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParsePlugins is already initialized
                                                 at com.parse.ParsePlugins.set(ParsePlugins.java:39)
                                                 at com.parse.ParsePlugins$Android.initialize(ParsePlugins.java:153)
                                                 at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:378)
                                                 at com.parse.Parse.initialize(Parse.java:331)
                                                 at com.goksuahmet.mekim.splash.onCreate(splash.java:16)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3930) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My Manifest
I write code from parse's site.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

-

```
<!--
  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
-->
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.goksuahmet.mekim.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.goksuahmet.mekim.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="oKsO63AavckYOzVOiwpUgUBEQhaGECkWiJLV6qti" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
        android:value="GoAN842J1l6WlQBUYFXl6AitgO1GFKB93BmU7Oc8" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyDM27rYpQ4wKwaFFyWU_CvJUHjaHdML-tg" />

    <activity android:name=".splash">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".neredeyiz"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".mekim_nasil"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />

    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <!--
              IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
            -->
            <category android:name="com.goksuahmet.mekim" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</application>
```

**My java**
I call to parse

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Parse.initialize(this);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);}
```

Why did my app shut down? How can I fix it? thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably called `Parse.initialize()` in some previous `Activity`. This method should be called only once in your app lifecycle. Rather create an `Application` class and add `Parse.initialize()` in its `onCreate` method. So do something like that:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this, getResources().getString(R.string.parse_app_id), getResources().getString(R.string.parse_client_key));
    }
```

After you've created `MyApplication` class you'll need to add it as an attribute (`android:name=".MyApplication"`) to your app manifest. This is how your manifest should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--
      IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
      to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
    -->
    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="com.goksuahmet.mekim.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.goksuahmet.mekim.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="oKsO63AavckYOzVOiwpUgUBEQhaGECkWiJLV6qti" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
            android:value="GoAN842J1l6WlQBUYFXl6AitgO1GFKB93BmU7Oc8" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDM27rYpQ4wKwaFFyWU_CvJUHjaHdML-tg" />

        <activity android:name=".splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".neredeyiz"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".mekim_nasil"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!--
                  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
                -->
                <category android:name="com.goksuahmet.mekim" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


    </application>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I do what did you say and I have different issue. When I send a push by parse my app gonna shut down. And logcat.

Comment: 'Process: com.goksuahmet.mekim, PID: 25243
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.parse.PushService: java.lang.NullPointerException'

Comment: Are you sure you were following every step in the [Parse quick start guide](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/new)? Because I can see that  Android permissions are missing in your manifest file, this could be maybe the problem...